# com.google.android.maps.MapView is not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hi i am trying to use MapView in my application but when i decalre a variable

```
package factual.box.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Factual_Mapping extends Activity{
    TextView txt;
    MapView android;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.factual_map);

    }

}
```

its showing MapView class doesnot exist
then i tried to find out the solution i have to install google api addon for android
but when i open sdk manager there is no such add on here is the screen shot

[image]

i used google maps at that time i downloaded that addon on a different machine but now its not showing please help how to use google maps and download addon.

Comment: It is not showing up because the SDK Manager is not done downloading, as you can tell by the incomplete progress bar at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "Google APIs by Google Inc.". Ensure you have that item installed for the Android API level you are using.

Also, in Eclipse make sure you are using the "Google APIs" version of the SDK. Right click your project, select properties, and under the Android tab set your project build target to "Google APIs" for the API level you need to use.

Comment: yes Google APIs by Google Inc. but its not showing in my sdk manager so i copy paste addon folder from my friends laptop and now its working fine for me.